# Where can you set a form field to required in the DB

Tags: field, plugin-sproutforms, required

Can someone point me to where in the DB you set a field as required? I am actually wanting to do this on a Sprout Forms field I am not sure if that makes a difference or not. I can't find which table you would do that in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Craft, fields can be shared across field layouts and there's no way to set a field as required across the board. A field can only be declared as "required" in the *context of a field layout*.

Usually this is easily done by clicking the cogwheel next to a field inside a tab in the field layout designer, and selecting "Make required". Sprout Forms uses the standard field layout designer, so you'll have this option here as well – though I'm guessing you have a specific reason for wanting to do it in the database.

In order to set a field (in a field layout) as required, first you'll need to know the *field's ID*. This is easily found by looking at the `craft_fields` table.

Next, you'll need to know the ID for the *field layout* you want to modify. In this case, you want the layout used by a specific Sprout Form, so the easiest way is to look at the `fieldLayoutId` column in the `craft_sproutforms_forms` table. *For entries, you have to look at the `craft_entrytypes` table, for categories, you'll have to look at the `craft_categorygroups` table, etc)*.

Finally, you'll need to identify the field in the `craft_fieldlayoutfields` table, by looking at the `layoutId` and the `fieldId` columns. Set the `required` column for the appropriate row to `1`, and you're done.

Comment: Hi Mats, thank you for your detailed response. The only reason I am needing to do this is because there seems to be a JS bug that prevents me from setting the field to required. So this is just a temp fix so that I can carry on testing until the main bug is fixed.